# Is there a way, using Imacros for Firefox, to extract an image from within a DIV that has a certain class?

Tags: html, image, class, extract, imacros

I'm not sure of the syntax within iMacros (10.0.2.1450, which has been paid for, and is being run on Firefox Quantum 66.0.3) to extract an image from within a DIV with a particular class

I have tried to look up info on the iMacros wiki and have Googled extensively, but am not sure how to extract the image, when I think the type needs to be DIV with a particular class as the Attribute.

`TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ALT:*&&SRC:*&&CLASS:particularclass EXTRACT=HREF`

This is the code on the site I'm trying to extract the image from

`<div class="particularclass">
<img alt="sample" src="https://sample.com/sample.jpg">
</div>`

I'm trying to save this image. I don't want to find it on the page based on any details of the image, I want to find it on the page by finding the div with a particular class, and saving the image within that div

When I tried the following, it's not finding an image with this class:

`TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ALT:*&&SRC:*&&CLASS:particularclass EXTRACT=HREF`

If anyone can help with the syntax, I'll be eternally grateful!
Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Yep, use 'Double Relative Positioning'... with the 'DIV' as 'main Anchor'... (Several Code Examples on the iMacros Forum...)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @chivracq. Checking through all the stuff on the forum now. Had hoped there was a way to be able to pull the image directly from within a div with a certain class. But I think I've got my head around the Double Relative Positioning. Will post back once I've done some more research ;)

Comment: Well, not very difficult to understand, I've already explained several times the Principle in Details, especially in the "oldest" Threads when I had first "introduced" the Concept... - And last time I had checked even Google would find directly those Threads with only those 3 Keywords (with Double Quotes), no need to mention "iMacros" nor my Name...

Comment: Thanks again for replying. I hope I haven't upset you with any questions. I'm still new to iMacros, so trying to learn as much as I can while working. What I meant by getting my head around it, was that I thought what I was trying to do was just a syntax issue. I thought I'd be able to get theimage by naming the class of the div or something. Obviously not so, so thanks again for the info on the relative positioning

Comment: You're right about the searching, I could have googled those three words and found all the info. My searches started with

IMACROS FIREFOX EXTRACT IMAGE FROM DIV WITH CLASS

I was searching for the wrong concept, so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:*replaceWithATTRclass*EXTRACT=*replaceWithATTRname*
```

Try this code, replace *replaceWithATTRname* with the name of the ATTR you want to extract, and replace *replaceWithATTRclass* with your class. You can also change the Type accordingly along with the position.

Comment: Thanks Joey. I've tried something similar to this, but I'll go again with your example and see what I come up with! I'll let you know how I go!

Comment: Hey Joey, I just tried the following

`TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:particularclass EXTRACT=IMG`

and I got this error:
BadParameter: expected EXTRACT=TXT|TXTALL|HTM|TITLE|ALT|HREF|CHECKED as parameter 5, line: 12

So I'm wondering if can't extract an IMG? You said I needed to be extracting the AttributeName, but this is the code on the site:

Comment: `<div class="particularclass">
<img alt="sample" src="https://sample.com/sample.jpg">
</div>`

I'm not sure what you mean by AttributeName in regards to the code above. Do you have an example? The alt and src of the image is dynamic and changes for every page, but the class of the div is the same on every page, so I weas really hoping to grab the image from within the div that has a class of "particularclass"

Thanks for your help so far ;)